# Creating shape around Europe especially France using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, europe

I want to create shape around Europe especially for France. But I'm not really sure how to do it as I am new in QGIS. Can I get any good suggestion for this task?

I'm attaching a picture which shows what I actually want. As it is presented yellow line shows the shape which we made using QGIS and I want to do the same thing around France.[image] Any suggestions so far? Is there any external package do I need to use? Moreover I want to do this work automatically rather than manually.

I'm using QGIS 2.18.2 version.

Comment: Have you tried using the Buffer vector method?

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx, Can you please explain in detail because i am new in QGIS. How can i create shape around european countries.

Comment: It looks like you already have a buffer around France. If you still have the QGIS project that that image is from, all you need to do is select the France buffer and QGIS will highlight it in yellow.

Comment: @csk, Yes it is working for one part of frane but the question is how can i make this buffer for other part of france.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to just download the country boundaries. They are freely available from many sources. For example:

http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data

It's a little unclear what you're asking, but if what you want to accomplish is a buffer around France, import the data linked above into QGIS, select France, right click the layer in your TOC, and Save As. Make sure to check Save only Selected Features.

[image]

Then import your new shapefile for France. Go to Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Fixed Distance Buffer to create the shape around France.

Comment: Thankyou for your response. but i don't think so that's what i am looking for. I need to add another shape around european countries as it is presented in the image mentioned above.

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you were asking then. Does the yellow line represent a buffer around the east coast of Britain? You want to do the same around the border of France?

Comment: Yes it is like a buffer around britian, But i'm not sure how to create the same buffer around france. Do you have any idea how to apply buffer?

Comment: Thank you for your answer yes i am looking the same thing but i need to create the same buffer as it is in piture mentioned above. Do, you have any idea how much distance or segments do i need to give while creating this buffer i tried many but didn't work out for me.

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to use the Measure Line tool on the toolbar to see how wide the buffer is.